# Aggregate Stock Realtime Data, generate an average Price and persist it in a Database

Tags: database, websocket, architecture, stock, real-time-data

I am stuck on an architecture problem I suppose.

**My Use-Case is the following:**

- write a service that is aggregating real time stock market data (interval about 1 second +) via websocket connections to different exchanges
- Somehow cache the results from the various exchanges
- generate an average price for every distinct stock, according to the aggregated data
- persist the generated price every few seconds
- On persisting, have another Service to listen for changes in the db, something like an event trigger
- Now send newly inserted data to all subscribed clients

**I have several questions:**

- Which db would be best for my use case? I just found out that mongodb has a watch functionality. **Java Example** https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver/tutorials/change-streams/
- How should the layer, that shall generate the average data, receive information?
- How should I cache the aggregated data from the exchanges while preparing for generating an average?
- While the average generation shall happen every 3-5 seconds, its necessary to take only what is there (in the cache), so if an exchange doesn't answer in the specified interval, the average should be generated anyway. Is this a valid approach?

**Technology Stack so far**

- I am using **golang** to implement the websocket connection to the several exchanges.
- For delivering the data to subscribed clients with a small webservice, I also wanted to use **golang**.
- I havent made up my mind for a properly fitting database so far.
  Hopefully the provided information is enough to answer my querstion.

Best regards

Comment: Just a couple question to better frame your problem.
What reason do you have to persist your averaged value? Is it for logging? will the actual data be needed somehow later? 
What if you just generated the average, post it to all the subscribers... except that your storage system is a subscriber too, and after receiving the message will store it?

Comment: Thx for your question. Yes the data will be needed to draaw a historical chart. In the best case I am able to show an ohlcv/candlestick chart of the averaged data. Somehow a Problem is, that the websocket connection to every exchange is sending messages all the time, but they are not in sync. So when exchange A answers now with a dataset, exchange b answers 150 ms later, but I need the data from b and a and any other connected exchange to generate an average. Im not sure how to implement the layer, thats waiting for every exchange to answer.

Comment: Additionally, what happens to all the messages that are "lost" while waiting for the other exchanges to answer? Do u get what I mean? kind regards

Comment: So you store the messages continuosly and generate the average once every, I dunno, 20 seconds, hoping that in 20 seconds you got all the responses?
This is not very "resilient": what if one of the systems you are querying goes offline for 10 minutes, maybe due to a problem on your side of the network?
Maybe you should relax your concept of average and make it more like "average of all the data we collected in the past X seconds", maybe providing a confidence rating if you could not get all the data in time?

Comment: (I am trying to understand if you absolutely need to store the data collected first - and then calculate the average, or if you can calculate the average based on the constant inflow of data, and persist it afterwards)

Comment: Thx for ur comment. I only need the avg data, so its possible to generate the avg from the inflow of data each x seconds. By storing the inflown data I dont really mean persisting them. I thought more in a cached way. This is quite a complex scenario, thats why I am asking here. :) In such a heterogene scenario, there will always be a certain error (like not answering exchange for example). This error should be known at that certain point in time and should be recorded/marked, to show it to the user or to see if there is a certain problem with the api.

Comment: U have an opinion on how such a system should be engineered. This is what I am interested in. So how should this system be designed? :) regards

Comment: I wonder if we shouldn't move this discussion to some other format (chat? emails?) - in case you can find my own website (in the StackOverflow profile) and then send me an email through it.